# Countdown applet, capable of counting down long periods of time?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, gnome-panel, applet

I want to add an applet to my panel, which would count down time for one event in the near future - ~12 days from today. Standard timer-applet does not work - it is not possible to set timer to more than 48 hours.

Is there a ready applet for this?

Or if there is no such applet, is it hard to write one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify the existing applet.

Open a terminal type :

`sudo gedit /usr/share/pyshared/timerapplet/ui/DurationChooser.py`

change the line `MAX_HOURS = 48` to `MAX_HOURS = 336`(for a maximum of 14 days) restart the applet and you won't be limited by 48h any more.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I needed!